# Heroku warning deploying to non-production when multiple apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, production-environment

I have a one codebase multiple websites (for UK, US etc) setup on Heroku with Rails 4. All works, except when I push to Heroku I see this in the terminal:

```
 remote: ###### WARNING:
 remote:        You are deploying to a non-production environment: "production_uk".
```

I have these production rails envs:

- production
- production_uk
- production_us

In my gemfile (and also some other files) I have these environments configured so for example I load puma but I was wondering if I should mind this warning? Maybe heroku treats non-production apps with lower priority or something like this?

I even tried to name rack env "production" while keeping rails env "production_uk" but that had no effect.

Thanks in advanceí!

Comment: It doesn't matter what environment you deploy the app to as long as it's supported in the backend.

Comment: that sounds good, thanks

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are not setting RAILS_ENV to production, heroku I believe warns you if this is not set.

are you using RAILS_ENV to control your country? if so instead use a different variable for that purpose.

It sounds like you are using RAILS_ENV to control which country the server is supporting.  This is why heroku is giving you the warning.  It expects to see RAILS_ENV='production'.

I would recommend you set up a separate environment variable (i.e. COUNTRY) and use this to control the country specific configuration of your app rather than than RAILS_ENV

Comment: sorry if I was not clear enough, I am new to this. I do use RAILS_ENV